# Site.createExternalUser does not send password email to user

Tags: customer-community, passwords, user-registration

I have created a custom self-registration page for a community in a sandbox. I am using `Site.createExternalUser(user, accountId, password)` with a null password password parameter to create the portal user.

The user is successfully created but the password email is not being sent to the user.  Email deliverability is set correctly.  If I manually reset the user password through Setup, then I do receive a password email, so I know there's no issue with email filtering or spam folders.

Has anyone run into this before?

BTW: I am letting the method create the portal account contact, so the only thing that exists before I call the method is the account.

Here is the code that sets up the User object.  `prf` is a customer community profile, `cr` is a wrapper that holds the portal account Id.

```
u = new User(
        FirstName = cr.firstName,
        LastName = cr.lastName,
        Username = cr.email,
        Email = cr.email,
        CommunityNickname = nickname,
        ProfileId = prf.Id,
        EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
        TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York'
);
// Setting a null password will send password email to user
String userId = Site.createExternalUser(u, cr.accountId, null);
```

Comment: Can you check and make sure email deliverability is turned on? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_send_through_salesforce_configure_deliverability.htm&type=5

Comment: Yes it is set to All Email.

Comment: Does the email being used already belong to a contact on the account Id you're using? I would check the documentation and read the User parameter carefully. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm#apex_System_Site_createExternalUser_2

Comment: No, I'm always using a different email address when I test.

Comment: Check if profile of the user is in list of community/site "Members" in Administration.

Comment: Is your community configured to send out a welcome email?